# Angular 2 two way data bindings and tabs

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am working with angular2 and ionic2.
I have two tabs. the first one contains a calculable field

```
 <ion-item >
              <ion-input class="size-amount" text-center type="text" [(ngModel)]="finalAmount"  name="finalAmount"></ion-input>
              <ion-icon  [ngClass]="{'hide': true }" name="finalAmount"></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>
```

the second tabs contains the discount of this finalAmount. i get the input and i do the calculation on the second tabs.

so if i go back to the first tabs i notice that the final Amount doesn't change. it will change only if i go back to the previous component with the "back" button.
i have this idea to work with the custom two way data bindings but i don't think that will resolve my problem because i can't work with two two data binding in the same input

tabs 1 : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndhvr.png)

tabs2 :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJNMm.png)
how can i resolve it
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If every tab is a component then you will have to share data between them.
Your way to share data is with:

1. events - inject service to both components and set a property on this service to hold your data
2. events - by input and output where parent component old the data
3. redux - store, but it is for bigger apps

and more options, I will go in this case with services.